# Swimmer on a beach

Tags: calculus, optimization

A swimmer is on the beach at a point A. The closest point on the
straight shoreline to A is called P. There is a platform in the water at B, and
the nearest pont on the shoreline to B is called Q. Suppose that the distance
from A to P is 100 meters, the distance from B to Q is 100 meters and the
distance from P to Q is a meters. Finally suppose that the swimmer can run
at 5 meters per second on the beach and swim at 2 meters per second in the
water.

[Here's a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq3o3.png)

The problem asks to prove that  $\dfrac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)}=\dfrac{5}{2}$ which I did through calculus.But i was wondering if there is a way to find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The distance in the water is $\sqrt{10000+x^2}$, thus the time spent there is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10000+x^2}$. Similarly, the time spent on the beach is $\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{10000+(a-x)^2}$. To get to the platform as fast as possible, we have to minimize
$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10000+x^2} + \frac{1}{5}\sqrt{10000+(a-x)^2}$. Differentiating yields $\frac{2x}{4\sqrt{10000+x^2}}-\frac{2(a-x)}{10\sqrt{10000+(a-x)^2}}$, thus we have to solve
$$20x\sqrt{10000+(a-x)^2} = 8(a-x)\sqrt{10000+x^2},$$ and squaring yields
$$3999936x^2 +336x^2(a-x)^2-640000(a-x)^2=0$$.

So you ended up with a somewhat general equation of degree 4, and although there is a solution formula for such equations, the resulting expression becomes pretty complicated. However, for each given $a$, a numerical colution of this equation can be found easily.